# Return a list in dplyr mutate()

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a function in my real-world problem that returns a list. Is there any way to use this with the dplyr mutate()? This toy example doesn't work -:

```
it = data.table(c("a","a","b","b","c"),c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,2,2))

myfun = function(arg1,arg2) {

temp1 = arg1 + arg2
temp2 = arg1 - arg2
list(temp1,temp2)

}

myfun(1,2)

it%.%mutate(new = myfun(V2,V3))
```

I see that it is cycling through the output of the function in the first "column" of the *new* variable, but do not understand why.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not supported currently but will be in the next version of dplyr. (At least for data.frames, given Arun's comments it's not clear that data.table lets you use lists as columns)

Comment: @hadley, the first line on the `data.table` [homepage](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) is: "Fast subset, fast grouping, fast assign, fast ordered joins and `list columns` in a short and flexible syntax". It does support. Given that he mentions that the output is being "cycled", I'm guessing Brodie's answer is what he's expecting. RonRich, please show us how the output should look like.

Comment: brodie's output is correct. i will post a new question with a data.table orientation that illustrates my real world issue more clearly.

Comment: @Arun got it - I was just confused because data.table normally turns lists into columns

Comment: please see here -: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663007/assigning-multiple-columns-in-data-table-with-conditional-function

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106593/4241780 for an updated `tidyverse` solution using `nest`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this using `data.table` would be to use the `:=` (assignment by reference) operator. Here's an illustration:

```
it[, c(paste0("V", 4:5)) := myfun(V2, V3)]
```

---

If you really want a list, why not:

```
as.list(it[, myfun(V2, V3)])
```

Alternatively, maybe this is what you want, but why don't you just use the `data.table` functionality:

```
it[, c(.SD, myfun(V2, V3))]
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1:  a  1  2  3 -1
# 2:  a  2  3  5 -1
# 3:  b  3  4  7 -1
# 4:  b  4  2  6  2
# 5:  c  5  2  7  3
```

Note that if `myfun` were to name it's output, then the names would show up in the final result columns:

```
#    V1 V2 V3 new.1 new.2
# 1:  a  1  2     3    -1
# 2:  a  2  3     5    -1
# 3:  b  3  4     7    -1
# 4:  b  4  2     6     2
# 5:  c  5  2     7     3
```

Comment: @Arun, gasp! when was the multi-variable in-place modification implemented?  I've been pining for that forever.

Comment: @BrodieG Looong time ago :)   Maybe 1.8.6 or earlier?

Comment: I'm not certain this is what the OP wanted. What if `myfun` was returning a linear model?

Comment: @hadley, try: `data.table(a=1:3, b=list(1, list("hello", "goodbye"), 3))`, but I haven't tested how gracefully this will behave...  Also, unclear at all what the OP wants, but based on the specific example he gave it looks like he's returning vectors of same length as original columns, so I doubt he's thinking of returning non conforming objects.

Comment: @hadley, more directly: `it[, list(list(myfun(V2, V3))), by=rep(1, nrow(it))]` where `myfun` returns an `lm` object.

Answer (score 1):

Given the title to this question, I thought I'd post a `tidyverse` solution that uses `dplyr::mutate`. Note that `myfun` needs to output a `data.frame` to work.

```r
library(tidyverse)

it = data.frame(
  v1 = c("a","a","b","b","c"),
  v2 = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
  v3 = c(2,3,4,2,2))

myfun = function(arg1,arg2) {

  temp1 = arg1 + arg2
  temp2 = arg1 - arg2
  data.frame(temp1, temp2)

}

it %>% 
  nest(data = c(v2, v3)) %>% 
  mutate(out = map(data, ~myfun(.$v2, .$v3))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(data, out))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   v1       v2    v3 temp1 temp2
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     2     3    -1
#> 2 a         2     3     5    -1
#> 3 b         3     4     7    -1
#> 4 b         4     2     6     2
#> 5 c         5     2     7     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The mutate() function is designed to add new columns to the existing data frame.  A data frame is a list of vectors of the same length.  Thus, you cant add a list as a new column, because a list is not a vector.

You can rewrite your function as two functions, each of which return a vector.  Then apply each of these separately using mutate() and it should work.