# Assigning multiple columns in data.table() with conditional function

Tags: r, data.table

In a previous question [Return a list in dplyr mutate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630406/return-a-list-in-dplyr-mutate?noredirect=1#comment32739594_21630406) it was clairified that although dlpyr cannot in release 0.2 create new variables from a vector returned by a function, data.table() can with the syntax -:

```
it[, c(paste0("V", 4:5)) := myfun(V2, V3)]
```

If the function `myfun` from that question is altered to -:

```
myfun = function(arg1,arg2) {


if (arg1 > arg2) {
temp1 = arg1 + arg2
temp2 = arg1 - arg2 }
else {
temp1 = arg1 * arg2
temp2 = arg1 / arg2 }
list(temp1,temp2)

}
```

the solution posted above returns a warning -:

```
it = data.table(c("a","a","b","b","c"),c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,2,2))
it[, c(paste0("V", 4:5)) := myfun(V2, V3)]

Warning message:
In if (arg1 > arg2) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

This implies that somehow data.table() is passing more than a single row to the function. Why is this occurring?

Comment: That warning is coming from your function. Just doing `myfun(it$V2, it$V3)` gives the same warning. It's because you are comparing two vectors (of length > 1) when doing `arg1 > arg2`. So, it takes just the first value (and provides the warning).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ron, this is expected behavior.  `data.table` always passes the full columns (unless you use `by`, in which case you get the part of the column that corresponds to each sub group).  In order to get around this, you need to vectorize your function:

```
myfun2 = function(arg1,arg2) {
  temp1 <- ifelse(arg1 > arg2, arg1 + arg2, arg1 * arg2)
  temp2 <- ifelse(arg1 > arg2, arg1 - arg2, arg1 / arg2)
  list(temp1,temp2)
}
```

I do this here using `ifelse` instead of `if/else`.  Then it works:

```
it = data.table(c("a","a","b","b","c"),c(1,2,3,4,5), c(2,3,4,2,2))
it[, c(paste0("V", 4:5)) := myfun2(V2, V3)]
it
#    V1 V2 V3 V4        V5
# 1:  a  1  2  2 0.5000000
# 2:  a  2  3  6 0.6666667
# 3:  b  3  4 12 0.7500000
# 4:  b  4  2  6 2.0000000
# 5:  c  5  2  7 3.0000000
```

Another alternative, if you don't want to modify your function, is to break up the `data.table` into one row groups.  We do this by passing a vector to `by` that has a distinct value for each row in the `data.table` (so that each row is a group):

```
it[, c(paste0("V", 4:5)) := myfun(V2, V3), by=1:nrow(it)]
```

Notice the `by` argument.  This also works, but is slower.  Generally, if you can vectorize you should.