# Return list using mutate and rowwise

Tags: r, list, function, dplyr, rowwise

I'm trying to return a list using mutate and rowwise but get the error shown in the code. These questions [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663007/assigning-multiple-columns-in-data-table-with-conditional-function) [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630406/return-a-list-in-dplyr-mutate) helped, but I'd like to keep it simple by iterating over rows using `rowwise()`, and the questions are 3yr 7mth old. Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)    
df <-  data.frame(Name=c("a","a","b","b","c"),X=c(1,2,3,4,5), Y=c(2,3,4,2,2))

    TestFn <- function(X,Y){
      Z <- list(X*5,Y/2,X+Y,X*2+5*Y)
      return (Z)
    }

    #this works
    SingleResult <- TestFn(5,20)

    #error - Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : incompatible size (4), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1
    dfResult <- df %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(R=TestFn(X,Y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TestFn` returns a 4 elements list per row, which can't really be fit in a row; You can wrap the returned elements in a vector first so the returned list is a single element list:

```
TestFn <- function(X, Y) list(c(X*5, Y/2, X+Y, X*2+5*Y))
#                             ^ 
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(R=TestFn(X,Y)) %>% pull(R)
#[[1]]
#[1]  5  1  3 12

#[[2]]
#[1] 10.0  1.5  5.0 19.0

#[[3]]
#[1] 15  2  7 26

#[[4]]
#[1] 20  1  6 18

#[[5]]
#[1] 25  1  7 20
```

---

`rowwise` is usually not as efficient, if you want to vectorize the solution, you can calculate the four expressions firstly and then transpose the result:

```
df$R = with(df, data.table::transpose(list(X*5, Y/2, X+Y, X*2+5*Y)))
df
#  Name X Y                    R
#1    a 1 2          5, 1, 3, 12
#2    a 2 3 10.0, 1.5, 5.0, 19.0
#3    b 3 4         15, 2, 7, 26
#4    b 4 2         20, 1, 6, 18
#5    c 5 2         25, 1, 7, 20
```

Comment: thanks, the first version works. The dataframe is small, approx 100 rows by 40 cols so speed isn't an issue - I just need a clean method to save and retrieve elements in each column list

Answer (score 3):

`tidyverse` lets you nest complicated data structures now

**tidyverse solution**

```
df %>%
  mutate(copyX = X, copyY = Y) %>%
  nest(copyX, copyY) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~TestFn(.x$copyX, .x$copyY)))
```

**output**

```
    Name     X     Y       data
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>     <list>
1      a     1     2 <list [4]>
2      a     2     3 <list [4]>
3      b     3     4 <list [4]>
4      b     4     2 <list [4]>
5      c     5     2 <list [4]>
```

**How to convert to data frame?**

Since your function returns a list, I added an additional step before `unnest`ing

```
df %>%
  mutate(copyX = X, copyY = Y) %>%
  nest(copyX, copyY) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~TestFn(.x$copyX, .x$copyY))) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~unlist(.x))) %>%
  unnest(data)
```

**output**

```
     Name     X     Y  data
   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      a     1     2   5.0
 2      a     1     2   1.0
 3      a     1     2   3.0
 4      a     1     2  12.0
 5      a     2     3  10.0
 6      a     2     3   1.5
 # etc
```