# How to get a column of lists of contract payout pairs (date:amounts)?

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

I'm trying to add a column of list objects to a data.frame of payments built like

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "B", "c", "A", "B", "c", "c", "A", "B")
Date = seq(as.Date("2000/07/01"), as.Date("2000/07/10"), "days")
Amt <- rnorm(10, 10, 3)

E <- data.frame(Date = Date, ID = ID, Amt = Amt)

         Date ID       Amt
1  2000-07-01  A  6.663256
2  2000-07-02  B 17.084491
3  2000-07-03  B  8.644242
4  2000-07-04  c  4.729045
5  2000-07-05  A  7.345490
6  2000-07-06  B  4.678909
7  2000-07-07  c  8.907506
8  2000-07-08  c  6.194540
9  2000-07-09  A  7.864848
10 2000-07-10  B 11.269177
```

First I use dplyr to build-out a few columns of desired summaries:

```
E.e <- E %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(contract_len = as.numeric(difftime(last(Date), first(Date), unit="days")),
            first_pay = first(Date),
            last_pay = last(Date),
            num_payments = n(),
            payment = sum(Amt)) 

E.e
Source: local data frame [3 x 6]

  ID contract_len  first_pay   last_pay num_payments  payment
1  A            8 2000-07-01 2000-07-09            3 21.87359
2  B            8 2000-07-02 2000-07-10            4 41.67682
3  c            4 2000-07-04 2000-07-08            3 19.83109
```

Now, I am trying to add a column of lists of key-value pairs, where keys are dates of a given ID's payments and values are the numeric objects describing the payment on that date.

I have tried these two approaches, but both throw errors I don't quite understand yet...

```
E.g <- E %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(E, stream = list( Date = seq(as.Date(first_pay), as.Date(last_pay)), Pay = Amt))
Error: impossible to replicate vector of size 3

E.e <- E %>%
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     summarise(contract_len = as.numeric(difftime(last(Date), first(Date), unit="days")),
               first_pay = first(Date),
               last_pay =last(Date),
               flightpath = list(d=Date, p=Amt),
               num_payments = n(),
               payment = sum(Amt))
Error: expecting a single value
```

My hacky interim solution is:

```
a = dplyr::filter(E, ID == 'A')
b = dplyr::filter(E, ID == 'B')
c = dplyr::filter(E, ID == 'c')

x.a = list(Date = a$Date,Pay = a$Amt)
x.b = list(Date = b$Date,Pay = b$Amt)
x.c = list(Date = c$Date,Pay = c$Amt)


x.a
$Date
[1] "2000-07-01" "2000-07-05" "2000-07-09"

$Pay
[1] 6.663256 7.345490 7.864848

E.e$stream = list(a,b,c)

E.e
Source: local data frame [3 x 7]

  ID contract_len  first_pay   last_pay num_payments  payment      stream
1  A            8 2000-07-01 2000-07-09            3 21.87359 <S3:data.frame>
2  B            8 2000-07-02 2000-07-10            4 41.67682 <S3:data.frame>
3  c            4 2000-07-04 2000-07-08            3 19.83109 <S3:data.frame>
```

But I obviously can't do this for all 1834 unique contract IDs in my full data set, and I think I should be able to do this with dplyr...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return a list in dplyr mutate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630406/return-a-list-in-dplyr-mutate)

Comment: @Metrics not committed to a dplyr solution, that's simply what I've used so far.  And in fact, my solution only uses dplyr to filter, then stores the 3 lists as a list in `E.e$stream`.

Comment: What are you doing to do with this data once it's in this form? Certainly this data will be difficult to work with since it's not a true rectangular data.frame. Most function in R won't work nicely with a data.frame that contains variable length lists. Does the data really need to be merged into `E.e`? `split(E[, c("Date","Amt")], E[, "ID"])` would get you most of the way there it seems.

Comment: I would like to take these stream lists, as well as another of the percentages of their total (spend/time) so that I can build S-curves with cumulative percentage points.  The (separate) lists would then look like `(date1%_oftotal : pay1%_oftotal ; date2%_oftotal : pay2%_oftotal, etc.)` and I would be mapping the original (numeric) start date to a point on a time line and building the cumulative S up in percentages from there.  (Think survival analysis like http://goo.gl/DhyvC0) @MrFlick

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. But storing that data in a data.frame (or tbl_df) in a non-rectangular way doesn't make sense (ie it will be far more difficult to work with)

Comment: @MrFlick isn't the express advantage of using the data.frame object is that it can hold different types of objects that need to be in the same row? Would it make more sense to make each of those stream lists the same (5296-day-long) length and just have that contract's payment stream on each?

Comment: Data.frames are great for storing atomic vectors of the same length but of different types. They work perfectly for rectangular data. But when you start nesting lists inside of cells things get awkward. No plotting function I know of would accept such a structure. Frankly, your E data.frame already seems most appropriate for the plot you describe. The "normalized form" of data base design generally apply to data.frame usage as well.

Comment: I can understand that advantage.  What if I build a 1834 x 5296 matrix of [contracts : continuous dates] and map what I have to those identically shaped payment streams? @MrFlick

Comment: That could be a useful format as well, again it all depends on what you need to do with it after you make it. We're getting pretty far off from your original question here. If there's something more specific you need to accomplish, perhaps you might start a new question with that specific task in mind. Different data configurations are required for different tasks. There's no one "right" way to store the data, but there are some that are easier to work with than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure why you want this, but here you go:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(E) # or convert in place using setDT

dt[, .(contract_len = as.numeric(difftime(Date[.N], Date[1], unit = 'days')),
       first_pay = Date[1],
       last_pay = Date[.N],
       num_payments = .N,
       payment = sum(Amt),
       summary = list(data.table(Date, Amt)))
   , by = ID]
#   ID contract_len  first_pay   last_pay num_payments  payment      summary
#1:  A            8 2000-07-01 2000-07-09            3 33.44106 <data.table>
#2:  B            8 2000-07-02 2000-07-10            4 37.83217 <data.table>
#3:  c            4 2000-07-04 2000-07-08            3 26.30531 <data.table>
```

And this is what the `summary` column looks like if you print it out:

```
#[[1]]
#         Date       Amt
#1: 2000-07-01 12.565032
#2: 2000-07-05 14.377863
#3: 2000-07-09  6.498166
#
#[[2]]
#         Date       Amt
#1: 2000-07-02  8.905060
#2: 2000-07-03 10.496663
#3: 2000-07-06  9.989162
#4: 2000-07-10  8.441285
#
#[[3]]
#         Date       Amt
#1: 2000-07-04  6.271645
#2: 2000-07-07  9.937350
#3: 2000-07-08 10.096318
```

Comment: There's a decent string of explanation in the comment string above.  Thanks much for this solution.

Comment: @D8Amonk np; I glanced through the comments and my guess is that your original data format already is in good enough format to do whatever you want

Comment: I will be posting a new question about my general approach for this project. I'm feeling around in the dark. I'd appreciate if I could get your input later on (u 2 @mrflick)